# How to get a prediction from Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I took the dynamic RNN example from aymericdamian: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/dynamic_rnn.py

and modified it a little to fit my data. The data is a list of 7500 data sets of 60 entries.

There are 5 labels as output data.

The code runs perfect and I get an accuracy of 75%.

Now I want to feed the model with a data set and get a predicted label back, but I get the following error:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype int32

The code is listed below and the two last lines is where I want to get the prediction back.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# ==========
#   MODEL
# ==========

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_iters = 1000000
batch_size = 128
display_step = 10

# Network Parameters
seq_max_len = 60  # Sequence max length
n_hidden = 64  # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 5  # large rise, small rise, almost equal, small drop, large drop

trainset = ToySequenceData(n_samples=7500, max_seq_len=seq_max_len)
testset = copy.copy(trainset)

# take 50% of total data to use for training
trainpart = int(0.2 * trainset.data.__len__())

pred_data = testset.data[testset.data.__len__() - 2:testset.labels.__len__() - 1][:]
pred_label = testset.labels[testset.labels.__len__() - 1:][:]

trainset.data = trainset.data[:trainpart][:]
testset.data = testset.data[trainpart:testset.data.__len__() - 2][:]

trainset.labels = trainset.labels[:trainpart][:]
testset.labels = testset.labels[trainpart:testset.labels.__len__() - 2][:]

trainset.seqlen = trainset.seqlen[:trainpart][:]
testset.seqlen = testset.seqlen[trainpart:testset.seqlen.__len__() - 2]

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, seq_max_len, 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
# A placeholder for indicating each sequence length
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


def dynamic_rnn(x, seqlen, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Permuting batch_size and n_steps
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    # Reshaping to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.split(0, seq_max_len, x)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)

    # Get lstm cell output, providing 'sequence_length' will perform dynamic
    # calculation.
    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32,
                                sequence_length=seqlen)

    # When performing dynamic calculation, we must retrieve the last
    # dynamically computed output, i.e., if a sequence length is 10, we need
    # to retrieve the 10th output.
    # However TensorFlow doesn't support advanced indexing yet, so we build
    # a custom op that for each sample in batch size, get its length and
    # get the corresponding relevant output.

    # 'outputs' is a list of output at every timestep, we pack them in a Tensor
    # and change back dimension to [batch_size, n_step, n_input]
    outputs = tf.pack(outputs)
    outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])

    # Hack to build the indexing and retrieve the right output.
    batch_size = tf.shape(outputs)[0]
    # Start indices for each sample
    index = tf.range(0, batch_size) * seq_max_len + (seqlen - 1)
    # Indexing
    outputs = tf.gather(tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, n_hidden]), index)

    # Linear activation, using outputs computed above
    return tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']

pred = dynamic_rnn(x, seqlen, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y, batch_seqlen = trainset.next(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                       seqlen: batch_seqlen})
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch accuracy
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                                seqlen: batch_seqlen})
            # Calculate batch loss
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                             seqlen: batch_seqlen})

            print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " +
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " +
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy
    test_data = testset.data
    test_label = testset.labels
    test_seqlen = testset.seqlen
    print("Testing Accuracy:",
          sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_data, y: test_label,
                   seqlen: test_seqlen}))
    print(pred.eval(feed_dict={x: pred_data}))
    print(pred_label)
```

Comment: You missed out the `seq_len` placeholder, check out explanation in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TensorFlow, when you do not provide a `name` to `tf.placeholder`, it assumes the default name `"Placeholder"`. The next placeholder created is named `"Placeholder_1"` and the third one is called `"Placeholder_2"`.

This is done to uniquely identify each placeholder. Now in your last line, you are trying to get the value of `pred.eval()`. Looking at your `dynamic_rnn` code, it seems like you need a value in the `seq_len` placeholder, which is the third placeholder defined (that's why `"Placeholder_2"`. Simply add the following key-value to your `feed_dict`,

```
print(pred.eval(feed_dict={x: pred_data, seqlen: pred_seqlen}))
```

Of course, you will need to define `pred_seqlen` properly like you defined the other two `seq_len` variables.